# 'Google API 8' cant be fetched from the addon url on the SDK manager?

Tags: android, macos, api, eclipse-plugin

I forgot to download Google Api 8 from SDK manager. I saw that on the first day i stared downloading the SDKs and APIs. Having a slow net speed i decided not to download at that time.

Now i need this. But the SDK manager cant fetch this. **Is there anyways to download and install the API externally?** Im using ecplipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some days ago i was also facing same problem The solution works for me is....

1.Get the latest window installer(i used r_14)

2.Also update the ADT plug-in

3.Start the SDK manager.

Now you should see the add-on

If not then Goto Tool option in sdk manager and click on Manage Add-on Site

click new and add the site- http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml

if this not works then add https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml

Now you will definitely able to download the add-on.

NOTE -I also search for externally download but nowhere found it.It is only downloadable from sdk manager.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why do you want to try the http url firstly, and not https? Usually Google states that one should try https before http.

Comment: sorry that i forgot to mention that im using Mac os x

Comment: i m not sure about mac but you can add these site there is no matter what you will try first.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to select the option Android SDK Tools under Tools in SDK Managaer and click on install, now Google API option will appear automatically for every SDK version.

Comment: so that it will update the Android SDK Tool to the latest revision, in my case its rev. 17