# how to get android google api for 2.2 version?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-2.2-froyo

I am building an application using google maps. And i need to use google api level 8, 2.2 for that. I have got update 14 in my eclipse but I cannot see google api 2.2 under android 2.2 drop down list. What can be the problem?

Comment: you need to download google api from SDK manager. Have you downloaded it?

Comment: @PareshMayani thats what i want to do from sdk manager..but the option is not showing.

Comment: check out [this link][1] . 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979700/google-api-8-cant-be-fetched-from-the-addon-url-on-the-sdk-manager/7979897#7979897

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Goto Tool option in sdk manager and click on Manage Add-on Site

click new and add the site- https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml

if this not works then add http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml

Now you will definitely able to download the add-on.

Answer (score 4):

According to my SDK manager which is R14 see the screen shots below

[image]
[image]

Select the Package you want and click Install Packages..

when you create a new project you will have this available and you can include Google Api based codes

Comment: @Harsha... yes..i know...but that option is not showing for me..its only showing sdk platform, samples for sdk... thats it.

Comment: which version of SDK Manager u have ? previously you have to choose a  section which said Google Api.. can u put a screenshot of ur SDK Mang

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this link  https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml to Manage Add-on Site and restart SDK manager after that. That helped me only after a few restarts

Answer (score 0):

Check on your Android SDK Manager if, on the "Show" options, you have selected "Updates/New", "Installed" and "Obsolete"

Comment: Yes, they are ticked..i mean selected.